# Datatables keeps rejecting my valid json response

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to create a Datatable which will show json data obtained from a DB.

Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3IzP.png)

This is the form I'm using, pretty simple.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table id="BusquedaProyectos" class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ProyectoID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Descripcion</th>
          <th>Aplicacion</th>
          <th>Nivel</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#BusquedaProyectos').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "BusquedaProyectos.php",
        "aoColumns": [
              { mData: 'ProyectoID' },
              { mData: 'NombreProyecto' },
              { mData: 'Descripcion' },
              { mData: 'AplicacionesProyecto' },
              { mData: 'NivelTRL' }
            ]
      });  
  });
</script>
```

And this is the valid json respone

```
Connected successfully - values obtained [{"ProyectoID":"36","NombreProyecto":"CocinaBot","Descripcion":"Etto","AplicacionesProyecto":"Aplicaciones","NivelTRL":"4"}]
```

This is the php file

```
<?php
require_once('conexionDB.php');

$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM proyectos");
$stmt->execute();

if (!$stmt){
    echo 'Error al ejecutar la consulta';
}else{
    echo '- values obtained ';
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($results);
}
?>
```

When I refresh the site, I get a modal:

```
DataTables warning: table id=BusquedaProyectos - Invalid JSON
```

I'm out of ideas.

Thank you, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

open the devtools in your browser and switch to the network tab ,Click the XHR option at the bottom of the window to reduce the requests to just the Ajax (XHR) requests and double click the Ajax request made by DataTables then check Click the response tab in the Ajax view to see the exact data that was returned from the server. you will find the `Invalid JSON` reason there !